# Normalise with countplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The code below shows a graph with the numbers of values in my list:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot([0,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3])
plt.show()
```

I would like the same plot with percentages instead. Is there an easy option with seaborn or matplotlib?

Comment: Do you have the code for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1027) a countplot which shows normalized values can be easily achieved using a seaborn barplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = [0,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3]
percentage = lambda i: len(i) / float(len(x)) * 100

ax = sns.barplot(x=x, y=x,  estimator=percentage)
ax.set(ylabel="Percent")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, using pandas,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = [0,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3]

ax = (pd.Series(x).value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False)*100).plot.bar()
ax.set(ylabel="Percent")
plt.show()
```

[image]